# Add new task to JobScheduler by PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-jobscheduler

As new Background Service Limitations was released by Android Team ["here"](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html), there is a problem to start Intent Service by setting a click Pending Intent on Widget(home-screen) Button in Android O. My question is: How can i add a new task to JobScheduler by click on Widget Button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is little to no I/O involved in scheduling the job, have the app widget button use a broadcast `PendingIntent` to trigger `onReceive()` in a `BroadcastReceiver`. In `onReceive()`, schedule your job.

In principle, you can use that even for work that involves I/O, using `goAsync()` in the `BroadcastReceiver` to do a tiny bit of work on a background thread. Or, use a service `PendingIntent` to invoke an `IntentService` that only does the I/O necessary to schedule the job.

Comment: As i understand, pending intent will not start on android O, because they have restriction on startService(), same for broadcast that registered in android manifest (not runtime). So the main question, is widget providers have restriction as receivers in manifest. Just need to test it on android o preview

Comment: @AndrewZabarowski: "pending intent will not start on android O" -- the ban is not on `PendingIntent`. The ban is on starting a service while you are in the background. Not only are notifications exempt from that ban, but there is `getForegroundService()` on `PendingIntent`, in case you wanted to start a foreground service.